# How to get modelattribute from GET to POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am making a Spring MVC project and i want to register new user.In my first page user sumbit his details like full name,address,mobilenumber etc when user enter the details i will send a OTP on his mobile and Store OTP in CacheLoader.Then i redirect the otp page and also use flashAttribute to use in OTPController GET method.I want when user enter OTP the full data comes to POST method and i will validate OTP then i save the full data in DB.

**UserDetailsController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("addUser") UserPojo userPojo, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model modelMap, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    otpService.clearOTP(userPojo.getPhoneNumber());
    boolean validate = adminUserService.uniqueUserName(userPojo.getUserName());
    if (validate == false) {
        int otp = otpService.generateOTP(userPojo.getPhoneNumber());
        String response = smsService.sendOtp(otp, userPojo.getPhoneNumber());
        if(response.equals("OK")) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("addUser", userPojo);
        logger.debug(addUserPojo.toString());
        return "redirect:/userotp";
        }
        logger.debug("response is-OTP Failed");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Problem is Send OTP");
        return "redirect:/admin/adduser";
    }
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "UserName Must Be Unique");
    return "redirect:/admin/adduser";
}
```

**OtpController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userotp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddUser(@ModelAttribute("addUser")  UserPojo userPojo,
        final BindingResult mapping1BindingResult, final Model model, ModelMap map,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    logger.debug("Enter in the Method" + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    logger.debug("Data is" + addUserPojo.toString());
    return "userotp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userotp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateUser(
        final BindingResult mapping1BindingResult, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.debug("Enter in the Method" + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return "userotp";
}
```

**userotp.html**

```
<form:form  method="post">
        <div class="" role="document" style="padding: 0px 30%;">

            <div class=" box">
                <h5 class="">User Moblie No. Verify</h5>
                <div class="">
                    <label>Moblie Number For Otp</label> <form:input type="number"
                        class="form-control" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP"/>
                    <br> <br>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verify</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

I want to get data UserDetails in OtpController POST method.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `@SessionAttributes`. To use `@SessionAttributes` we can store `modelAttribute` in Session and when there is no use of `modelAttribute`. We can remove it.

We can remove it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userotp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validate(@ModelAttribute User user, WebRequest request, SessionStatus status) {
     // your business logic 
    status.setComplete();
    request.removeAttribute("user", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
    return "userotp";
}
```